# Sorting string array with numbers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have problem solving this problem.
The task is simple at first line I enter how many examples I have. 
On second line I need to enter how many numbers im going to read.
and then we enter all the numbers separate by space.
The task itselfs do , sorting the string array wtih numbers from smalles to the biggest one. After that if we have even numbers entered we print the middle number -1, if they are uneven we just print the middle number.

So far if I use the exact same code with long long it works perfectly , but it is limited only to 19 digit number and I want to expand the program so it can use bigger numbers.

Using that way the sort func , when I try to sort 16 elements from 160 to 10 , they all messed it start from 110 then in the midle is 160 and so one , which makes absolutly non sense,  using 5 numbers or 8 works perfectly w/o any problem , using more numbers fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;




int main() {
int examples;
cin >> examples;
for (size_t i = 0; i < examples; i++)
{
    long long unsigned int  n;
    cin >> n;
    string * numbers = new string[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    sort(numbers, numbers + n);

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        cout << numbers[n / 2 - 1];
    }
    else
        cout << numbers[n / 2];



}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: There are a few "bignum" libraries. Try and search a little.

Comment: take a look at `__int128`

Comment: You also have a memory leak in your program. I suggest you use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Lastly, if you insist on using strings, try making all strings the same size and pad the short strings with *leading* zeroes.

Comment: its not about using big num librarier , I want to make it with string , and apperently the whole problem is in the sort func itself, when I try to sort from 160 to 10 it prints 10, 110,120,130,140,150,160,20,30 ... so it cleary thinks that 110 is smaller then 20 which is WTF , so it definetly not sum all the ASCI code numbers from all numbers if the sort use to sum 110 asci code aka - 49+49+48 it will be bigger then 20 which is 50+48 so I suppose I need to write my own algorithym to sort string :S..

Comment: It's not a WTF. It's how *strings* works when sorted. The string `"10"` *is* "smaller" than the string `"2"`. Take a look at [an ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) to understand why (`'1' < '2'`)

Comment: You should add padding yourself. Also, you can use std::nth_element to get your answer (n-th element), as it's quicker than sort.

Comment: Yes because sort func sorting 1 < 2  and dont  care about others numbers maybe thats the way they wrote it but in my case comparing numbers is total non-sense, only If I could get my hands on the sort func( cant find it ) and there should be made just a little change and everything will work perfectly ;(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you allocate memory with operator new, you must release it with operator delete[].

Second, when you sort strings instead of values, they are sorted just like strings would do, and here is where your problem lies. You see, 100 is alphabetically less than 2 or 20, that's why it would appear earlier.

Here's the output your program gives. Check this rule out, and you'll see that i'm right.

```
10 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Third, using operator new is discouraged for pretty much anything. You have STL, and you seem to be using it extensively - why not vector?

Fourth, you don't check if anything we write into numbers[i] is actually a number. Think on that.

Fifth, for N being long enough(more than 2^sizeof(size_t)) your problem will NEVER stop due to integer overflow.

Sixth, you don't check for n == 0, and you will ultimately get memory access violation if you enter it.

A fast-right-off-the-bat fix for your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int examples;
    cin >> examples;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < examples; i++)
    {
        size_t n;
        cin >> n;
        if (n <= 0)
            break;
        vector<string> numbers(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> numbers[i];

        //here we add a predicate for string checking,
        //which evaluates the length of string
        //before using the usual operator<.

        sort(begin(numbers), end(numbers), [](const string& s1, const string& s2){
            if (s1.length() < s2.length())
                return true;
            if (s2.length() < s1.length())
                return false;
            else
                return (s1 < s2);
        });

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            cout << numbers[n / 2 - 1];
        }
        else
            cout << numbers[n / 2];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Still, it has a number of problems:

1. Checking if numbers[i] is actually a number
2. I'm not sure that
   predicate I wrote doesn't have bugs - I'm just trying to give you
   the idea of how it should work.

Comment: Thank you a lot , for the clearence you made, I did know that the only way was to compare the length of the string but I really had lack of knowledge to rewrite the sort func as you did. 
As for the other problems they arent that impornt , this is just a homework :) .
It is in conditions that it will be always a positive number  the n between 1 and 10^6 and the numbers itself always positive from 1 to n^20+  :)

Comment: Check out this post about lambda expressions(that modification to sort that I made), it will give you an idea about what i've done here: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lambdas-in-c11/240168241

Comment: Also, good luck in your training, people here do not like newcomers with sorta easy tasks, and consider them lazy, but they've all been on that road, me included :)

Comment: Thanks once again , yes sometimes ppl refuse to help you , because think you dont deserve a help or something like that cause maybe your way to bad or I dont know , in my situation I was aware of the alogorithym and what I need to do, I can also write my self a quicksort and do the same w/o using in-built function , but the task was to be able to use large numbers(string only). I knew that the only way is to compare strings length but as I said lack of knowledge(nobody teaches us) how to rewrite the sort function as you did!

Comment: Just a simplification of the comparison function:
`[](const string& s1, const string& s2){
    if (s1.size() != s2.size()) { return (s1.length() < s2.length()); }
    return (s1 < s2);
}`